# How is it possible to use a C# library in a QT project?

Tags: c#, windows, qt5

Is there any way to include a C# library in a QT project which is run in Windows operating system?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use an available [Qt language binding](https://wiki.qt.io/Language_Bindings) for C# and from those applications, you can import whatever external libraries you want.